# When virtualizing, is it possible for a host OS to be compromised through the guest OS?

Tags: security, virtual-machine

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can virtual machines infect their host?](https://superuser.com/questions/190836/can-virtual-machines-infect-their-host)
>   [Virtual Machine and Virus](https://superuser.com/questions/48939/virtual-machine-and-virus)

Is the host OS isolated in terms of security? If I don't secure my VM could my Host OS be at risk? If it is secure then running windows in a VM on Linux may be the safest way to run Windows!

Answer (score 2):

In theory it is possible if there is a vulnerability in the virtual machine. In practice, there's no need to worry as long as you keep the networking locked down -- don't let the guest have access to your internal network except the specific route needed to get to the internet.

Comment: Vitalization is very much like sandboxing, it keeps the guest file system completely separate from the host, however, if you set it up as if they are peers on a network with any sharing privileges, then one can be infected by the other as if they were both normal machines on a network.

Comment: so if I have a shared folder setup between the guest and host, that could be a potential target?

Comment: @Shogun: Unlikely but possible

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it has been demonstrated. [See also this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/190836/can-virtual-machines-infect-their-host/190871#190871). Although I'd agree that it is not very common yet.