# Can Malware Jump From Virtual Machine To Core O.S

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, malware

I See Many Youtubers use Virtual Machine to Isolate their Operating System From Malware Infection...Is there Anything I Have to Do to isolate my OS from being Jumped by Malware If Ever i try To Run A Malware In My VM?

Comment: It would require taking advantage of a bug in the Hypervisor. Meltdown for example could in theory escape a Hypervisor.  However, that would require the multiple things to be true

Comment: Historically there have been exploitable bugs discovered in the hypervisor (purplePill), or in hardware (spectre/meltdown), so yes it is possible, but those kinds of exploits need to be leveraged purposefully so a VM is still a great precaution (especially because you can control network interaction). that said though, most malware researchers keep their samples encrypted, so that the code cannot be accidentally executed . I recall talking to an expert who used multiple layers of encryption, because it allowed him a more failsafe workflow when working with others.

Comment: This question has been asked a million times. E.g. [Virtual Machine and Virus](https://superuser.com/questions/48939/virtual-machine-and-virus)